# Python freezes on While loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

So I am writing a simple game, in which these lines exist:

```
import random

def Start():

    print "STEP1.1" #Print statements for debugging

    door1 = random.randint(1,3)
    door2 = random.randint(1,3)
    door3 = random.randint(1,3)

    print "STEP1.2"

    while door1 == door2:
        door2 == random.randint(1,3)

    print "STEP1.3"

    while door1 == door3 or door2 == door3:
        door3 = random.randint(1,3)

    print 'STEP1.4'
```

This code is meant to give `door1`, `door2`, and `door3` random unique values between 1 and 3. It stops working on step 1.3, because it prints until step 1.2 then freezes with a blinking cursor (does NOT print `STEP1.3`) This fails, but

```
x = 0
while x < 100:
    print "HI, IM ",x
    x = x + 1
```

prints everything until `HI I'M 99` then stops, therefore it works.

I'm using Python 2.7. sometimes the code works and gives me random unique values for each of the doors, but it often crashes as well.

Comment: In first while loop you are using `door2 == random.randint(1,3)`. It generates a random number and check equality but it does not set the value of `door2`. That is why infinite loop

Comment: @kuro why does it not set the value of door2? there is a equals sign and it's a while loop, and so when door2 is different to door1, the loop breaks?

Comment: @techgenius101 No. `==` means testing if both values are equal. To assign the value to the door2, you should use `door2 = random.randint(1,3)` (simple `=`)

Comment: @Dunatotatos Oh I see what I did. I didn't make the same mistake on door3, which is good. Thank you.

Comment: @Kuro Your comment is a valid answer, please go ahead and put that as an answer :)

Comment: The devil is hidden in the details. Double equal `==` checks if two objects are equal, single `=` means assignment. You do not assign anything to the door2 (as you do in the door3). Check your code thoroughly before you post. I'm pretty sure you could solve this with just basic knowledge of Python and programming in general.

Comment: And BTW, a few comments about the code. To assign unique random values to the doors, it would be much better to have a list of door numbers (e.g `door_numbers = [1,2,3]`), then shuffle (`random.shuffle(doors_numbers)`), then assign the doors (`door1 = door_numbers[0]`). While it does not make a huge difference here, your solution is extremely slow if you have a huge number of doors.

Comment: And for debugging purpose, I recommend to use a debugger `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` instead of `print` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In first while loop you are using `door2 == random.randint(1,3)` after step 1.2. The `==` checks if the two sides are equal or not, while `=` assigns values to a variable. So, in your case `randint` generates a random number and check equality but it does not set the value of `door2`.

It may be a simple typo by yourself and correct code should be

```
door2 = random.randint(1,3)
```

Comment: He actually deserves to accept his answer. Please do.

Answer (score 3):

In first while loop...
*while door1 == door2:
        **door2 == random.randint(1,3)***
You are using comparision operator **==**.It should be **=**.This is causing problem.

Answer (score 2):

If door1 equals door2, your check (by using ==), if door2 is a random int in range (1,3). Because that is correct, you loop to infinity. Better use a = instead of a == to assign door2 a new random int in range (1,3).